# What is the connection between an isometric angle and scale

Tags: mathematics, isometric, projection, trigonometry

I am trying to work out an isometric projection matrix for a custom angle.
In the engine I'm using there's a projection matrix defined like so:

```
projection.rotate(45 * (Math.PI / 180) );
scale = 1.4142137000082988; // not sure why this magic number is needed- now working on a "real" solution
projection.scale(scale * 1, scale * .5);
```

I'm currently trying to get my head around the [wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometric_projection#Mathematics).
I see the beta angle is 45, like in the matrix above, but I don't understand  where does the 'magic' number come from, and the connection between the isometric angle and the scale ratio (1,1/2).

If I want to use a custom angle, how do I work out what angle I use instead of 45 ? , what would the scale value and scale ratio be ?

Comment: Have you tried replacing 45 and the magic scale number with different values to just see what happens visually? That might make it easier to understand.

Also, I suspect that the scale number is just an arbitrary value that happens to produce a good looking result. I have no idea why it would be so precise, though.

Comment: I just realized that your scale number is very close to square root of 2.

Comment: yup, also to 1/cos(radians(45))